# jquery not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a dropdown category and sub category menu in jquery. The script is working n Firefox, chrome but not in IE6. could you please guide me to fix this problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#show_heading').hide();
    $('#search_category_id').change(function() {
        $('#show_sub_categories').fadeOut();
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post("get_chid_categories.php",
               {
                   parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
               },
               function(response) {
                    setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
               }
        );
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#show_heading').show();
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id() {
    if($('#sub_category_id').val() == '')
        alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
        alert($('#sub_category_id').val());
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what isn't working?

Comment: Lots of stuff doesn't work in IE6...

Comment: you could fix it by upgrading your IE :)

Comment: @Mud Dib — it's not the OP's browser that is the issue, it's the users'. Upgrading is **their** choice and they'll do it in their own time.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you need to specify what the error is and where it occurs (i.e. the error message that IE give you).

If you format your code so it is more readable, I think you'll discover a syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loader').hide();
  $('#show_heading').hide();
  $('#search_category_id').change(function(){
  $('#show_sub_categories').fadeOut();
  $('#loader').show();

  $.post("get_chid_categories.php",
    {
      parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
    },
    function(response){
      setTimeout("finishAjax('show_sub_categories', '" +
                  escape(response) +
                  "')",
      400);
    }
  );
  return false;
});
});  // <-- that is extra

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#loader').hide();
  $('#show_heading').show();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id() {
  if ($('#sub_category_id').val() == '') {
    alert('Please select a sub category.');

  } else {
    alert($('#sub_category_id').val());
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: about _"that is extra"_: You not properly reformat code. Your extra is end of _document_ready function()_, two lines before your "extra" is end of _$('#search_category_id').change_ function.

Comment: Ok, highlights that you need to properly format your code, don't leave it up to others.

Answer (score 1):

have you declared doc-type ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

you may have incorrect HTML . this may be an HTML issue .

please provide your HTML .

Comment: The DOCTYPE included in most documents served on the web bears no resemblance to how it is treated by the browser. The above is probably served as text/html and treated as HTML 4.01 transitional (or not). What issues do you thing the DOCTYPE will cause with either DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 1):

Removed escape|unescape and eval in setTimeout.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#show_heading').hide();
    $('#search_category_id').change(function() {
        $('#show_sub_categories').fadeOut();
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post("get_chid_categories.php",
               {
                   parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
               },
               function(response) {
                    // CHANGED
                    var f=function(){finishAjax('show_sub_categories',response);};
                    setTimeout(f, 400);
               }
        );
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#show_heading').show();
    // CHANGED
    $('#'+id).html(response);
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id() {
    if($('#sub_category_id').val() == '')
        alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
        alert($('#sub_category_id').val());
    return false;
}
</script>
```